# How to create a function that removes all of a selected character in a C-string?

Tags: c++

I want to make a function that removes all the characters of ch in a c-string.
But I keep getting an access violation error.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000f17ba in testassignments.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000f787e.
```

```
void removeAll(char* &s, const char ch)
{
    int len=strlen(s);
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == ch)
        {
            for(j = i; j < len; j++)
            {
                s[j] = s[j + 1];
            }
            len--;
            i--;    
        } 
    }
    return;
}
```

I expected the c-string to not contain the character "ch", but instead, I get an access violation error.
In the debug I got the error on the line:

```
s[j] = s[j + 1];
```

I tried to modify the function but I keep getting this error.

Edit--
Sample inputs:

```
s="abmas$sachus#settes";
ch='e' Output->abmas$sachus#settes, becomes abmas$sachus#stts
ch='t' Output-> abmas$sachus#stts, becomes abmas$sachus#ss.
```

Instead of producing those outputs, I get the access violation error.
Edit 2:
If its any help, I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Comment: This requires a [mcve].

Comment: "I tried to modify the function", please explain how and show an [mcve] of that, too. Along with sample input, desired output and current output (if any before the runtime error).

Comment: What happens in the last inner loop, when j==(len-1), len still equals strlen and you access s[j+1]?

Comment: May I suggest we speak the same dialect? I can guess that `charPointer` is an alias for `char*`, but it's less clear than just using the correct type explicitly.

Comment: What do you intend with this line? `len--;`

Comment: What do you intend with this line? `i--;`

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah my bad, I forgot to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the last edit with sample input. Please also provide [mcve] for both/all of your code versions.

Comment: @Yunnosch Honestly, I am not completely sure, len-- and i-- might be one of the causes of the error.

Comment: @Yunnosch I will try, this is my second ever question so I am still not familiar with the formats of questions here.

Comment: I doubt it. They seem harmless (though one of the is probably spoiling the purpose of the program). My other question (in my second comment) is what I bet on. That looks like a good way to cause an access violation.

Comment: If you do not know the purpose of each line in your code, then I recommend this text  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Put the "debugging" aside and concentrate on the many parts about understanding your own code.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm afraid you are wrong.  Reading `s[j+1]` is perfectly valid, since the largest value it can be is `s[len]`.  On the surface, that might look like an overflow, but that's because you forgot strings are null-terminated, and `strlen` does not count the terminator as part of the length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the inefficiency of your function shifting the entire remainder of the string whenever encountering a single character to remove, there's actually not much wrong with it.

In the comments, people have assumed that you are reading off the end of the string with `s[j+1]`, but that is untrue.  They are forgetting that `s[len]` is completely valid because that is the string's null-terminator character.

So I'm using my crystal ball now, and I believe that the error is because you're actually running this on a string literal.

```
// This is NOT okay!
char* str = "abmas$sachus#settes";
removeAll(str, 'e');
```

This code above is (sort of) not legal.  The string literal `"abmas$sachus#settes"` should *not* be stored as a non-const `char*`.  But for backward compatibility with C where this is allowed (*provided you don't attempt to modify the string*) this is generally issued as a compiler warning instead of an error.

However, you are really *not* allowed to modify the string.  And your program is crashing the moment you try.

If you were to use the correct approach with a `char` array (which you *can* modify), then you have a different problem:

```
// This will result in a compiler error
char str[] = "abmas$sachus#settes";
removeAll(str, 'e');
```

Results in

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘char*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘char*’

So why is that?  Well, your function takes a `char*&` type that forces the caller to use pointers.  It's making a contract that states *"I can modify your pointer if I want to"*, even if it never does.

There are two ways you can fix that error:

1. The *TERRIBLE PLEASE DON'T DO THIS* way:

   ```
   // This compiles and works but it's not cool!
   char str[] = "abmas$sachus#settes";
   char *pstr = str;
   removeAll(pstr, 'e');
   ```

   The reason I say this is bad is because it sets a dangerous precedent.  If the function actually *did* modify the pointer in a future "optimization", then you might break some code without realizing it.

   Imagine that you want to output the string with characters removed later, but the first character was removed and you function decided to modify the pointer to start at the second character instead.  Now if you output `str`, you'll get a different result from using `pstr`.

   And this example is only assuming that you're storing the string in an array.  Imagine if you actually *allocated* a pointer like this:

   ```
   char *str = new char[strlen("abmas$sachus#settes") + 1];
   strcpy(str, "abmas$sachus#settes");
   removeAll(str, 'e');
   ```

   Then if `removeAll` changes the pointer, you're going to have a *BAD* time when you later clean up this memory with:

   ```
   delete[] str;  //<-- BOOM!!!
   ```
2. The *I ACKNOWLEDGE MY FUNCTION DEFINITION IS BROKEN* way:

   Real simply, your function definition should take a pointer, not a pointer reference:

   ```
   void removeAll(char* s, const char ch)
   ```

   This means you can call it on any modifiable block of memory, including an array.  And you can be comforted by the fact that the caller's pointer will never be modified.

   Now, the following will work:

   ```
   // This is now 100% legit!
   char str[] = "abmas$sachus#settes";
   removeAll(str, 'e');
   ```

---

Now that my free crystal-ball reading is complete, and your problem has gone away, let's address the elephant in the room:

Your code is needlessly inefficient!

1. You do not need to do the first pass over the string (with `strlen`) to calculate its length
2. The inner loop effectively gives your algorithm a worst-case time complexity of **O(N^2)**.
3. The little tricks modifying `len` and, worse than that, the loop variable `i` make your code more complex to read.

What if you could avoid all of these undesirable things!?  Well, you can!

Think about what you're doing when removing characters.  Essentially, the moment you have removed one character, then you need to start shuffling future characters to the left.  But you do not need to shuffle one at a time.  If, after some more characters you encounter a second character to remove, then you simply shunt future characters further to the left.

What I'm trying to say is that *each character only needs to move once at most*.

There is already an answer demonstrating this using pointers, but it comes with no explanation and you are also a beginner, so let's use indices because you understand those.

The first thing to do is get rid of `strlen`.  Remember, your string is null-terminated.  All `strlen` does is search through characters until it finds the null byte (otherwise known as `0` or `'\0'`)...

[Note that real implementations of `strlen` are *super* smart (*i.e.* much more efficient than searching single characters at a time)...  but of course, no call to `strlen` is faster]

All you need is your loop to look for the NULL terminator, like this:

```
for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Okay, and now to ditch the inner loop, you just need to know where to stick each new character.  How about just keeping a variable `new_size` in which you are going to count up how long the final string is.

```
void removeAll(char* s, char ch)
{
    int new_size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] != ch)
        {
            s[new_size] = s[i];
            new_size++;
        } 
    }

    // You must also null-terminate the string
    s[new_size] = '\0';
}
```

If you look at this for a while, you may notice that it might do pointless "copies".  That is, if `i == new_size` there is no point in copying characters.  So, you can add that test if you want.  I will say that it's likely to make little performance difference, and potentially reduce performance because of additional branching.

But I'll leave that as an exercise.  And if you want to dream about *really fast* code and just how crazy it gets, then go and look at the source code for `strlen` in *glibc*.  Prepare to have your mind blown.

Comment: Thank you so much for the long and amazing answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can make the logic simpler and more efficient by writing the function like this:

```
void removeAll(char * s, const char charToRemove)
{
   const char * readPtr = s;
   char * writePtr = s;

   while (*readPtr) {
      if (*readPtr != charToRemove) {
         *writePtr++ = *readPtr;
      }
      readPtr++;
   }
   *writePtr = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Even if OP should consider this an answer, do you really think that writing the function from scratch (even if better) will help OP as much as possible? Finding and explaining the problem in OPs code would be more of a learning experience.

Comment: Sorry, but what does the line ```while(*readPtr)``` do? I don't think I've learned that yet.

Comment: See? I think that last OP comment supports my doubt.

Comment: That while, checks that the location of memory in which readPtr is not null. Look how that is incremented at the end of the while loop. If you did not follow what I explained, no problem. Come back to this question/answer in a few weeks. It seems you have yet to learn about pointers. Don't worry - it will come soon.

Comment: @elcuco Oh I see, I understand it's just that I was taught to write it something like while(readPtr[index] != 0) and increment the index slowly.

Comment: @JovS the way you have been tough is very explicit, and is OK for your level of expertise. However - the "!= 0 " is not used outside of the first stages of learning, and eventually C/C++ compilers evaluate "0" to "false" and "1" to true. 

`while readPtr[index]` and `while readPtr[index] != 0` are the same code.